# How to stop automatic authentication to a network drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, windows-server-2008

I have a network drive I will call `\\fs`. I have two sets of credentials: `user` and `admin`. I am automatically authenticated to `\\fs` as `user` through some dark magic which I do not understand. This happens on my work laptop as well as my work VMs. Depending on where I am and what I'm doing, I may be using any of multiple accounts spread across two domains.

Sometimes, I need to sign in as `admin` to do some specific work. However, this is always an enormous pain pursuant to the previously mentioned sorcerer's curse. In order to clear my current session with `\\fs` and be prompted for credentials again, I have tried deleting the batch file from the Startup folder which automatically maps `\\fs`, logging out and in of Windows, clearing everything in credential manager without mercy, and running `net use /d *`. After doing this, I log in, open windows explorer, enter `\\fs` into the address bar, and it signs me in as `user`.

What do I have to do to get my credentials cleared? Is this something with the network configuration? I am pretty sure that, at some point in the past, I was able to clear my credentials and log in as admin. I just can't figure out how. Thank you!

Comment: Are you logged in to a domain?

Comment: @dsolimano Yes, I have multiple accounts over two domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot suggest a permanent solution to your problem. I have a suspicion this behavior may be enforced by your domain policy.

However you can try the following:

lets assume your `\\fs` is mapped to drive `X:`, then first of all disconnect it and delete the information about the mount point:

```
net use X: /delete
```

The command that you have specified in your original question will do the job as well, but be careful as it will remove all mapped drives.

Then reconnect `\\fs` but make sure to specify the user:

```
net use X: \\fs /user:YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME\YOUR_USER_NAME
```

You may as well want to use another command if you are not concerned about typing the your password in cmd

```
net use X: \\fs /user:YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME\YOUR_USER_NAME YOUR_PASSWORD /persistent:no
```

Comment: This is good enough for me as I am fine with the default authentication most of the time. Also, for some reason `net use X: \\fs ...` wouldn't work and I had to use `net use X: \\fs\Vol1`